# Brainf**k Debugger

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck

Your challenge is to take input like this (a Hello World program):

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
```

And output a prompt (which will be `"> "`):

```
>
```

The user can then enter anything at the prompt. Your simple debugger must have these commands:

- `S` - step

  - Output the current location (see `L`) after stepping.
  - `S(a positive integer)` - step that many spaces
- `L` - location

  - The term "location" always refers to where you are in the program (i.e., the instruction pointer).
  - Formatted like this:

    ```
      v
    +++++++[>+++++++<-]>.
    ```

    This means that the current location of the program is at the third `+`.
- `G(an integer)` - go to

  - This means keep stepping until you get to that location. If you reach the end of the program and you haven't gotten there, simply exit the program.
  - A negative integer means that many characters from the end. Yes, this means that `-0` is different than `0`, and `-1` is the second to last character.
  - Don't output anything for this command.
- `D` - dump array

  - Formatted like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
  - If the array is `1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...`, only output `1, 2, 3`.
  - `D(a positive integer) (a positive integer)` - dump all array items between those two positions (inclusive)
- `(a positive integer)` - output the item currently at that array position
- `P` - output the index of the BF pointer (the thing you change with `>` and `<`).

When the program requests input, show the prompt `"I> "`. (You may input one character at a time.)

When it outputs something, show `"O> " + (the output)`. Multiple outputs between commands must be chained together (i.e. you can't do `> G-0 O> H O> e O> l O> l O> o ...`, it has to be `> G-0 O> Hello, World!`).

Output "Done" and exit once you reach the end of the program.

---

Sample run:

```
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
> S
1
> S
2
> S2
4
> S0
4
> L
    v
++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.
> D
4
> 0
4
> D10 15
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
> G-0
O> Hello, World!
Done
```

Sample run showing stepping through loops and the `P` instruction (calculates `3*2+1`)

```
+++[>++<-]>+
> S3
3
> L
   v
+++[>++<-]>+
> S3
6
> L
      v
+++[>++<-]>+
> P
1
> S3
9
> L
         v
+++[>++<-]>+
> S
3
> L
   v
+++[>++<-]>+
> D
2, 2
>
```

Sample run showing I/O

```
>+[>,---------------------------------]<[<]>[>.]
> G37
I> H
I> e
I> l
I> l
I> o
I> !
> D
0, 39, 68, 75, 75, 78
> G-0
O> 'DKKN
Done
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code will win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PHP - 1008

```
<?php
$_=trim(fread(STDIN,1e5));$z=$p=0;$t=$l=[];$q='';function s(){global$p,$t,$l,$_,$q,$z;switch($_[$z++]){case'>':$p++;break;case'<':$p--;break;case'+':@$t[$p]++;break;case'-':@$t[$p]--;break;case'.':$q.=chr($t[$p]);break;case',':echo"I>";$t[$p]=ord(trim(fread(STDIN,2)));break;case'[':$l[]=$z;if(!isset($t[$p])||$t[$p]==0){$c=1;while($c>0){$b=$_[$z++];if($b=='[')$c++;elseif($b==']')$c--;}array_pop($l);}break;case']':$z=array_pop($l)-1;break;}if($z==strlen($_)){if($q)echo'O>'.$q."\n";die("Done\n");}}for(;;){echo">";$c=trim(fread(STDIN,1e5));$g=strlen($c);switch($c[0]){case'L':echo str_repeat(' ',$z)."v\n".$_."\n";break;case'D':if($g)$x=$t;else{list($a,$b)=explode(' ',substr($c,1));$x=array_slice($t,$a-1,$b);}echo implode(', ',$x)."\n";break;case'S':if($g)s();for($i=0;$i<substr($c,1);$i++)s();echo $z."\n";break;case'G':if($c[1]=='-')$x=strlen($_)-substr($c,2);else$x=substr($c,1);while($z!=$x)s();break;case'P':echo$p."\n";default:if(is_numeric($c))echo$t[$c]."\n";}if($q)echo'O>'.$q."\n";$q='';}
```

The output for cells that were never written is slightly different:

```
[timwolla@/data/workspace/php/PCG]php pcg-22585.php
+
>D15 20

>
```

Large version:

```
<?php
$_=trim(fread(STDIN,1024));
$z=$p=0;
$t=$l=[];
$q='';

function step() {
    global $p, $t,$l,$_,$q,$z;
    switch ($_[$z++]){
        case '>': 
            $p++; 
        break;
        case '<': 
            $p--; 
        break;
        case '+': 
            @$t[$p]++; 
        break;
        case '-': 
            @$t[$p]--; 
        break;
        case '.': 
            $q.=chr($t[$p]); 
        break;
        case ',': 
            echo "I>";
            $t[$p] = ord(trim(fread(STDIN, 2)));
        break;
        case '[': 
            $l[] = $z;
            if (!isset($t[$p]) || $t[$p] == 0) { 
                $counter = 1; 
                while ($counter > 0) { 
                    $char = $_[$z++]; 
                    if ($char == '[') $counter++;
                    else if ($char == ']') $counter--;
                }
                array_pop($l);
            }
        break;
        case ']': 
            $z = array_pop($l)-1;
        break;
    }
    if($z==strlen($_)) {
        if ($q) echo 'O>'.$q."\n";
        die("Done\n");
    }
}

for(;;){
    echo ">";
    $c=trim(fread(STDIN,100));
    switch ($c[0]) {
        case 'L':
            echo str_repeat(' ', $z)."v\n".$_."\n";
        break;
        case 'D':
            if(strlen($c) == 1)$x=$t;
            else {
                list($a,$b)=explode(' ',substr($c,1));
                $x=array_slice($t,$a-1,$b);
            }
            echo implode(', ', $x)."\n";
        break;
        case 'S':
            if(strlen($c)==1)step();
            for($i=0;$i<substr($c,1);$i++)step();
            echo $z."\n";
        break;
        case 'G':
            if($c[1]=='-')$x=strlen($_)-substr($c,2);
            else $x=substr($c,1);
            while ($z!=$x)step();
        break;
        case 'P':
            echo $p."\n";
        default:
            if(is_numeric($c)) echo $t[$c]."\n";
    }
    if ($q) {
        echo 'O>'.$q."\n";
        $q='';
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed the third testcase.